# What if dark matter occupied three other dimensions and it could only interact with our three dimensions through gravity and time?

Tags: cosmology, universe, dark-matter, spacetime-dimensions

I recently thought about dark matter existing in three other dimensions similar to ours but wasn't sure if it was logical. It would be of great help if someone would give me a clear insight into this topic.

Comment: There is research on these lines , see https://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2013/713508/ .see this simple review of dark matter https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/what-could-dark-matter-be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is logical as a conceptual proposal in that it breaks no known laws of physics, but there is no underlying mathematical model which would suggest it, in fact quite the reverse.

One would have to extend the theories of higher dimensions quite fundamentally in order to accommodate it, and there are reasons why this would in practice be problematic.

For example the theory would have to explain why and how the six extended spatial dimensions were grouped in threes and no other natural phenomena could cross the divide. Also, we have reasons for limiting the maximum number of dimensions to twelve. Three each, plus time, leaves only five for string theories, which is not enough to accommodate all of quantum physics.

Nevertheless, I regard it as about equal in validity to the idea that our 10-dimensional "string" world is a "brane" floating in an 11- or 12-dimensional plenum and that gravity is so weak because it leaks away into the plenum. Your dark Universe could be just a parallel brane, perhaps containing all the missing antimatter, whose gravity is leaking into ours. Given such speculative brane models, why not add yours to the mix?